# Ember. JQuery. Reading JSON google news feed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, angularjs, ember.js

I am trying to read the rss feed of google news in an Ember app:

```
App.RandomRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
 return $.getJSON('https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss').then(function(data){
    return data.posts.map(function(post){
        post.body = post;
        return post;
     });
 });

 }
});
```

But:

```
"Error while loading route: undefined"
```

I don't know anything of Jquery, I think the problem it's that I have to do an ajax call. I have also tried something like in Angular:

```
return $.getJSON('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&q=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=')
```

but it's not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you are pointing to, https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss, returns an XML file, so that's certainly not going to work since `$.getJSON()` is expecting the returned feed to be JSON.

To get the feed in a JSON format, you can use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&q=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss You can type both of these links into your browser and see the results.

As @vishwanath pointed out though, you have to worry about the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) issue and therefore resort to using JSON-P instead. The good news is that `$.getJSON()` already supports this, so all you have to do is tack on `&callback=?` and you are good to go (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) - do a search for JSONP on the page).

Also, take a look at the structure of the JSON feed coming back to you. There is `responseData`, which contains the `feed`, which in turn contains `entries`

So, your final **working** code could be something like this. (I just grabbed the ember starter kit...)

Your app.js file:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
     return $.getJSON('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?' +
                  'v=1.0&num=50&q=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&callback=?')
         .then(function(data){
         return data.responseData.feed.entries.map(function(entry){
            var post = {}; 
            post.title = entry.title;

            return post;
         });
     });
 }});
```

Your index.html file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul>
      {{#each model}}
        <li>{{title}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your exact problem. But you need to use jsonp to make requests to google server from your domain. You can do that in following way using jquery.

```
      $.ajax({
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        url : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&q=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=',
        success : function(response) {
          console.log('response', response)
        }
      });
```

Comment: I have tried returning that instead of  $.getJSON but still not working

Comment: I have opened a new topic with the new problem, but you were right, I think I am closer now. Thank you very much.